# how to switch views and deallocate previous view's memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with several views, each view is its own view controller. I am switching views by using the following method.

```
TableViewSelect *tableview = [[TableViewSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController: tableview animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have been told in another question that this would cause the new view to be displayed over the previous view but without deallocating the memory. So as user flips though views, the memory is always growing. i.e. Memory leak. Can anyone tell me how to switch views where the memory is deallocated when leaving the view.

Thanks

Comment: FYI - technically it is not a memory leak. It's certainly wasted memory that will cause problems, but not really a leak.

Comment: One way to deallocate viewControllers view-related memory is to send it a `[targetViweController didReceiveMemoryWarning];` message. This is not really a good practice though - just a brute force option.

Comment: @rokjarc Calling `didReceiveMemoryWarning` does not deallocate view controller related memory. If a given view controller implements that method to clean up some cache or other "re-creatable" memory, then that little bit may be cleaned up but in no way will be view controller be deallocated. It's view is still in the view hierarchy and the view controller is still being referenced.

Comment: My bad. As of >= iOS6.0 what you say is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, it would be advisable to do:

```
//in TableViewSelect class on some action
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

Plus... depending on your flow, but say you have the following classes:

1. `AppDelegate`
2. `ViewController`
3. `FirstVC`
4. `SecondVC`
5. `ThirdVC`

Say:

- `AppDelegate`'s rootViewController is `ViewController`
- `ViewController` presents `FirstVC`
- `FirstVC` presents `SecondVC`

So now... you're on `SecondVC` and need to show `FirstVC` again, then in this case, to conserve memory, you'll need to dismiss `SecondVC`.

But... if you've something even remotely like:

- **`FirstVC` -> `SecondVC` -> `ThirdVC` (*back to*) -> `FirstVC`**

then you're better off with a `UINavigationController` because this seems like a potential memory hog.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display one view at a time, you could do something like this...

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIVIewController *currentViewController;

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:    (BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
        if (self.currentViewController != nil) {
            [self.currentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^{
                self.currentViewController = viewControllerToPresent;
                [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:animated completion:completion];
            }];
        } else {
            self.currentViewController = viewControllerToPresent;
            [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:animated completion:completion];
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes only one view is displayed at a time, switching views i want the new view to reload. Would i put the above code in each of the view controllers?

Comment: @user3521174 : why don't you use a `UINavigationController` and make use of the `-pushViewController:animated:` & `-popViewControllerAnimated:` methods? ... just asking

Comment: @user3521174 You would put this code in the "root view controller" (the thing presenting all the different views).

Comment: @user3521174 Your original question implied that you had one "main view" presenting multiple different views. Is this the case or do you have a more complex workflow?

Comment: i have a login screen which goes to main screen, from the main screen, you can go to a third view. From the third view you go to a fourth. From the fourth you can go to the third view or the main view. To get to the login screen from the main screen. If you send me a message i'll reply with a picture of this lol. I don't have the reputation to put pictures on

Comment: Use a navigation controller. It gives you methods to push views onto the stack and then pop views off the stack when you need to go "back".